# Getting an "Enumeration values 'x', 'y' and 'z' not handled in switch" message when, in fact, these enumerations are being handled. What's going on?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, switch-statement, enumeration

I have an enumeration defined as such:

```
//ModelClass.h
typedef enum { Automatic, Manual, Off } MyModes;
```

Later, in a ViewController, I have a switch statement within a method that switches on a variable of my enumeration type.  My switch statement looks as follows:

```
//MyViewController.m
#import "ModelClass.h"

-(void) dryer:(MyClass *)m didChangeMode:(MyModes) newMode
{

    //Code within an instance method, utilizing the above enumeration
    switch (newMode) //newMode is an instance of MyMode enum.
    {
    case Automatic:
        //Some code...
        break;
    case Off:
        //Some code...
        break;
    case Manual:
        //Some code...
        break;
    }
}
```

The above switch statement was copy/pasted from my code and all I did was replace the functional code with the `//Some code...` comments.

XCode keeps giving me a warning at the `switch (newMode)` line stating "Enumeration values 'Automatic', 'Manual', and 'Off' not handled in switch".

Furthermore, at each `case` statement, I'm getting an error stating "Expression is not an integer constant expression", even though it should be since it's an enumeration.

How can I fix this?  The odd thing is that I have another enumeration in the `ModelClass` header (consisting of 4 enumerated items) defined on the following line after `MyModes` enumeration and, in my view controller, I have another method that is doing the exact same type of switch/case operation.  I am not getting a single warning or error on that method, using that enumerator.

What could be going on?

**EDIT**

I put the method declaration within the code snippet.  The `newMode` variable is a parameter to the method.  Furthermore, the aforementioned, other enumerator that is working correctly is also being passed into the other method as a parameter.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `newMode`.  Can you put together a small self-contained program that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @Keith, I modified my code to show the definiton of `newMode`, which is actually a method parameter.

Comment: No, they are much more verbose and no where near similar.

Comment: Well, hmm.. @Keith, apparently you were on to something.  I renamed (temporarily) these enumerations, putting a `_1` at the end of each one (i.e. `Automatic_1`, `Manual_1`, `Off_1`.)  This has fixed the problem.  The errors and warnings go away and my code compiles.  Post a solution and I'll give you the points.  This is such a weird bug, though.  I would have never guessed that this would have been the problem.  I imagine that there must have been some form of "collision" with on of the names.  Probably `Off`.

Comment: If I copypaste this exact code + add only the minimum amount of code (`@interface`, `@implementation`, `@class MyClass;`) to make it valid, it compiles just fine with clang.

Comment: Could you have some errant macro definitions for `Automatic`, `Off`, and `Manual` buried somewhere (maybe some sort of debugging helpers)?

Comment: Actually, I have three UIButtons that are names `Automatic`, `Manual` and `Off`.  So... the compiler wasn't smart enough to see that the variable that was switched off of was an enumeration (nor was I smart enough to name these values something else.)  I understand this is C compiler so that could be a bit to advanced.  Still, I had forgotten about the buttons and better error messages would have helped. :/

Comment: Oh, right - I had forgotten that enum identifiers can be hidden by simple variable declarations; macros aren't necessary to trample over the enum names.

Comment: If you declare something in an inner scope with the same name as something in an outer scope, the inner declaration simply hides the outer declaration.  Any time you refer to `Automatic`, for example, it will refer to the innermost declaration with that name; the outer one is invisible.  A sufficiently clever compiler might warn about this kind of thing, but in some cases that could result in a whole bunch of spurious warnings that you don't care about.  I'll summarize and post an answer.

Comment: Actually, since you found the solution yourself, perhaps you should post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of both [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) and [Micheal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) in the comments above, I have been able to solve this problem.  At Keith's suggestion, I am answering my own question.

This problem was my own fault because I had defined a few buttons within my ViewController, each respectively named `Automatic`, `Manual` and `Off`. The compiler assumed I was referencing my `UIButton`s and not the `enum` type because those were local-scope variables.

Renaming the enumerated values and updating the code fixed this bug.  In my case, I redefined my enumeration as such:

```
typedef enum { AutoMode, ManualMode, OffMode } MyModes;
```